# Change some GCC warnings into errors

Tags: gcc

In my makefile I specify [-Werror](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror)=uninitialized, but no errors occur.

I changed it to *[-Wuninitialized](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wuninitialized)*, and I see my warning. *-Wno-uninitialized* makes it go away as expected, but why isn’t *-Werror=uninitialized* working?

Also it was suggested in code I write

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wuninitialized"
```

But that does not work either. Why?

<sub>I have [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475407/make-one-gcc-warning-an-error), but unfortunately none of the suggestions are working for me.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use *[-Werror](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror)*. This option doesn't have any parameters (it is an on/off switch).

But it is good practice to remove all warnings, so *-Werror* enforces this good practice.