# Void * as return type is giving int value and warning: C

Tags: int, return, compiler-warnings, void-pointers

I am implementing my own malloc and am facing a small issue with the void*

When i print my returning addres in mem_alloc:

```
    printf("Addr p = %p\n", (void *)(p+ 1));
```

it gives me something like this:

```
    Addr p = 0x7f20f20b1050
```

But when i print the same returned pointer in mymain.c:

```
    p1 = (int *)Mem_Alloc(40879);
    printf("%p\n", p1);
```

I get: 0xfffffffff20b1050
This is leading to a seg fault in my mem_free

I return :

```
    return (void *)(p + 1);
```

I also got a warning for mymain.c: mymain.c:10: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size

The thing i do not understand is why is it becoming an integer type when i returned a void*

```
    for (p = freep; p != NULL; prevp = p, p = p->ptr) {
            if (p->size == size) {
                    if (prevp == NULL) {
                            freep = p->ptr;
                    } else {
                            prevp->ptr = p->ptr;
                    }
            } else if (p->size > size) {
                    p->size = p->size - size;
                    p = (Header *)((char *)p + p->size);
                    p->size = size;
            } else {
                    continue;
            }
            printf("Addr p = %p\n", (void *)(p+ 1));
            return (void *)(p+1);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the allocation function, or at least its relevant part?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Mem_Alloc's return type:

```
int Mem_Alloc(int size);
```

Whatever you return in the function above will be cast to int.

Edit:

The following code:

```
/* main.c */
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int *p1;
    p1 = (int *)Mem_Alloc(40879);
    printf("%p\n", p1);
}

/* mem_malloc.c */
void* Mem_Alloc(int size) {
    return (void*)0x7f20f20b1050;
}
```

Shows `FFFFFFFFF20B1050` on my Windows 8.1 / Visual Studio 2013 (x64), because if Mem_Alloc is not declared before it is called, [its return type will implicitly be `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9182835/1997315). Adding a line `void* Mem_Alloc(int size);` before `int main() {` can fix the problem.

Comment: The return type is void*

        void *Mem_Alloc(int size) {

Comment: @user1166419  Which is the 10th line of mymain.c?

Comment: 9: int *p1;
10: p1 = (int *)Mem_Alloc(40879); @jingyu9575

Comment: @user1166419 Did you declare Mem_Alloc before the call? I mean, did you have a line: void* Mem_Alloc(int size); before the 10th line?