# How to compile module with new kernel in Linux

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, kernel, kernel-module

After switching to Ubuntu 13.10 I need to compile a device driver for that newer kernel. Calling `make` results in 2 errors:

```
error: implicit declaration of function ‘kzalloc’
error: implicit declaration of function ‘kfree’
```

The same `make` command runs fine in Ubuntu 13.04, but fails now. I also checked the existence of

```
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
```

which is used in Makefile and that becomes `/lib/modules/3.11.0-18-generic/build` when parsed. The Makefile seems pretty standard compared to this [module compilation guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x181.html).

What did I miss when moving to 13.10? Are there additional packages necessary? The build-essentials package is installed. Did something else change in 13.10?

The **complete error message** for `make` is:

```
user1@pc:/etc/opt/elo-mt-usb/elo_mt_input_mod_src$ sudo make
make -C /lib/modules/3.11.0-18-generic/build SUBDIRS=/etc/opt/elo-mt-usb/elo_mt_input_mod_src modules 
make[1]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18-generic'
  CC [M]  /etc/opt/elo-mt-usb/elo_mt_input_mod_src/elo_mt_input.o
/etc/opt/elo-mt-usb/elo_mt_input_mod_src/elo_mt_input.c: In function ‘elo_input_write’:
/etc/opt/elo-mt-usb/elo_mt_input_mod_src/elo_mt_input.c:79:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘kzalloc’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  if(!(buffer = kzalloc(count, GFP_KERNEL))) 
  ^
/etc/opt/elo-mt-usb/elo_mt_input_mod_src/elo_mt_input.c:79:14: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  if(!(buffer = kzalloc(count, GFP_KERNEL))) 
              ^
/etc/opt/elo-mt-usb/elo_mt_input_mod_src/elo_mt_input.c:148:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘kfree’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   kfree(buffer);
   ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/etc/opt/elo-mt-usb/elo_mt_input_mod_src/elo_mt_input.o] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/etc/opt/elo-mt-usb/elo_mt_input_mod_src] Fehler 2
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18-generic'
make: *** [default] Fehler 2
```

The **Makefile** contains:

```
obj-m := elo_mt_input_mod.o 
elo_mt_input_mod-objs := elo_mt_input.o

KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules 

install:
    cp ./elo_mt_input_mod.ko ../elo_mt_input_mod_`uname -r`.ko

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.cmd *.mod.c .*.o* .*.ko* *~ *.ko Module.markers modules.order Module.symvers 
    rm -rf .tmp_versions/
```

Luckily, the manufacturer published the driver source under the GPL. The **elo_mt_input.c** file, that needs to be compiled,  is:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Name:    Linux input module for Elo MultiTouch(MT) devices
// License: GPL
// Author:  Elo Touch Solutions Inc
// Version: 1.0.0 
// Date:    26 August 2013
// --------------------------------------------------------------

//Header Files
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,38))
 #include <linux/input/mt.h>
#else
 #include <linux/input.h>
#endif

//Driver Information
#define DRIVER_VERSION  "1.0.0"
#define DRIVER_AUTHOR   "Elo Touch Solutions Inc"
#define DRIVER_DESC     "Linux input module for Elo MultiTouch(MT) devices"
#define DRIVER_LICENSE  "GPL"

// Kernel Module Information
MODULE_VERSION(DRIVER_VERSION);
MODULE_AUTHOR(DRIVER_AUTHOR);
MODULE_DESCRIPTION(DRIVER_DESC);
MODULE_LICENSE(DRIVER_LICENSE);

// Global Definitions
#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,38))
 #define _MULTITOUCH_KERNEL_
#else
 #undef _MULTITOUCH_KERNEL_
#endif

#ifdef _MULTITOUCH_KERNEL_
 #define ELO_MT_MAXCONTACTS 2  // Maximum number of multi touch contacts
#endif

#define MIN_X (0)    // Min X Axis resolution
#define MAX_X (4095) // Max X Axis resolution 

#define MIN_Y (0)    // Min Y Axis resolution 
#define MAX_Y (4095) // Max Y Axis resolution

#define MIN_PRESSURE (0) // Min Pressure 
#define MAX_PRESSURE (1) // Max Pressure

// Global Data Structures
struct touch_event {
 u16 touch_count;   // Total touch count in the entire frame
 u16 touch_index;   // Current Touch Index for this contact
 u16 contact_id;    // Contact ID for this contact
 u16 touch_status;  // Indicates if touch is active or not for this contact
 u16 x;             // ABS X value for this contact
 u16 y;             // ABS Y value for this contact
};

struct input_dev *elo_input_device = NULL;
struct proc_dir_entry *proc_entry = NULL;

// Functions
static ssize_t elo_input_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
 return 0;
}

static ssize_t elo_input_write(struct file *file, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
 int rc = -1;
 const u8 *ptr = NULL;
 u8 *buffer = NULL;
 size_t size = count;
 struct touch_event *event = NULL;

 if(!(buffer = kzalloc(count, GFP_KERNEL))) 
  {
   printk(KERN_ERR "elo_mt_input: Unable to allocate memory\n");
   rc = -ENOMEM;
   goto done;
  }

 if(copy_from_user(buffer, buf, count)) 
  {
   printk(KERN_ERR "elo_mt_input: Unable to copy data\n");
   rc = -EFAULT;
   goto done;
  }

 /* Process each touch event */
 ptr = buffer;

 while(size >= sizeof(*event)) 
  {
   event = (struct touch_event *)ptr;
   // printk(KERN_INFO "elo_mt_input: mt event touch#:%d cid=%d x=%d y=%d status=%d\n", event->touch_index, event->contact_id, event->x, event->y, event->touch_status);

#ifdef _MULTITOUCH_KERNEL_
   // Actions for sending Multitouch events  
   input_mt_slot(elo_input_device, event->contact_id); //Use contact_id for slot numbering [ max 2 slots ]
   input_mt_report_slot_state(elo_input_device, MT_TOOL_FINGER, event->touch_status);

   if(event->touch_status)
    {// If touch is active                  
     input_event(elo_input_device, EV_ABS, ABS_MT_POSITION_X, event->x);
     input_event(elo_input_device, EV_ABS, ABS_MT_POSITION_Y, event->y);
     input_event(elo_input_device, EV_ABS, ABS_MT_PRESSURE, event->touch_status);
    }
   // Send primary touch events to move the pointer
   input_mt_report_pointer_emulation(elo_input_device, true);

   // Check if this is the last touch event based on touch count and touch id, then send SYN_REPORT 
   if(event->touch_count == (event->touch_index + 1)) 
    {
     input_sync(elo_input_device);
    }
#else
   // Actions for sending Single Touch as Mouse events for primary touch only 
   if(event->touch_index == 0)
    {
     if(event->touch_status)
      {// If touch is active                  
       input_event(elo_input_device, EV_ABS, ABS_X, event->x);
       input_event(elo_input_device, EV_ABS, ABS_Y, event->y);
       input_event(elo_input_device, EV_KEY, BTN_LEFT, event->touch_status);
      }
     else
      {
       input_event(elo_input_device, EV_ABS, ABS_X, event->x);
       input_event(elo_input_device, EV_ABS, ABS_Y, event->y);
       input_event(elo_input_device, EV_KEY, BTN_LEFT, 0);
      }
     input_sync(elo_input_device);
    }
#endif

   ptr += sizeof(*event);       
   size -= sizeof(*event);
  }

 rc = count;

done:
 if(buffer)
  kfree(buffer);

 *ppos += count;
 return rc;
}

static const struct file_operations elo_input_fops = {
 .read  = elo_input_read,
 .write = elo_input_write
};

static int __init elo_input_init(void)
{
 int rc = 0;

 if(!(elo_input_device = input_allocate_device())) 
  {
   printk(KERN_ERR "elo_mt_input: Unable to create input_dev\n");
   rc = -EBUSY;
   goto done;
  }

 // Input device will report ABS events
 set_bit(EV_ABS, elo_input_device->evbit);

#ifdef _MULTITOUCH_KERNEL_
 // Setup for direct devices [touchscreens]
 set_bit(INPUT_PROP_DIRECT, elo_input_device->propbit);
 // Corresponding to HID TIPSWITCH field (Pointer emulation)
 input_set_capability(elo_input_device, EV_KEY, BTN_TOUCH);
 elo_input_device->name = "Elo MultiTouch(MT) Device Input Module";
#else
 // Corresponding to HID TIPSWITCH field - Send LEFT Mouse button event
 input_set_capability(elo_input_device, EV_KEY, BTN_LEFT);
 elo_input_device->name = "Elo Single Touch Device Input Module";
#endif


 // Set appropriate dimensions
 input_set_abs_params(elo_input_device, ABS_X,         MIN_X, MAX_X, 0, 0);
 input_set_abs_params(elo_input_device, ABS_Y,         MIN_Y, MAX_Y, 0, 0);

#ifdef _MULTITOUCH_KERNEL_
 input_set_abs_params(elo_input_device, ABS_MT_POSITION_X, MIN_X, MAX_X, 0, 0);
 input_set_abs_params(elo_input_device, ABS_MT_POSITION_Y, MIN_Y, MAX_Y, 0, 0);
 input_set_abs_params(elo_input_device, ABS_MT_PRESSURE,   MIN_PRESSURE, MAX_PRESSURE, 0, 0);
 input_set_abs_params(elo_input_device, ABS_PRESSURE,      MIN_PRESSURE, MAX_PRESSURE, 0, 0);

 // Corresponding to HID contact ID
 #if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(3,7,0))
  input_mt_init_slots(elo_input_device, ELO_MT_MAXCONTACTS, INPUT_MT_DIRECT);  // Kernel 3.7 or later [Added 3rd parameter - flags] 
 #else
  input_mt_init_slots(elo_input_device, ELO_MT_MAXCONTACTS); 
 #endif 
#endif 

 if((rc = input_register_device(elo_input_device))) 
  {
   printk(KERN_ERR "elo_mt_input: Unable to register input_dev\n");
   goto done;
  }

 // Create the proc entry
 proc_entry = proc_create("elo_mt_input", S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR, NULL, &elo_input_fops);

 if(proc_entry == NULL) 
  {
   printk(KERN_ERR "elo_mt_input: Failed to create /proc/elo_mt_input\n");
   input_unregister_device(elo_input_device);
   rc = -EBUSY;
   goto done;
  } 

 printk(KERN_INFO "elo_mt_input: Input device registered\n");

done:
 return rc;
}

static void __exit elo_input_exit(void)
{
 remove_proc_entry("elo_mt_input", NULL);
 input_unregister_device(elo_input_device);
}

module_init(elo_input_init);
module_exit(elo_input_exit);


//---------------------------------EOF---------------------------------
```

Comment: I pulled `linux-headers-generic` and `linux-headers-generic`. The directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18-generic` does exist.

Comment: There is another directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18` as well. So this pattern seems to conserved on Ubuntu, too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

kzalloc/kfree/etc. are declared in `<linux/slab.h>`, so you should include that header file.

Perhaps it got indirectly included through other header files you have included in the older versions, so it happened to work with an older kernel.

Comment: Yes, it compiles now! Thanks alot!

Comment: Got the module up and running! Works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

It might have something to do with function declarations in C.

Maybe you need to include some additional library?
[Implicit function declarations in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182763/implicit-function-declarations-in-c)

Comment: Yes, user nos gave a hint on the missing include.