# Lines 21,23,24,26,29 subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: string, uppercase, lowercase, chars

Its a code to convert lowercase chars in a vector to uppercase chars.
Im getting error in lines 21,23,24,26,29. Im newbie programing in C.
Please help me.

```
int main()
{
    char orig[30];
    char dest[30];

    printf("Write a string :");
      scanf("%s",orig);

      char uppercase(dest,orig);
       printf("uppercase string = ",dest);


}



char uppercase(char destination,char origin){

    int i = 0;

      while(origin[i]!='\0'){

         if(origin[i]>='a'&& origin[i]<='z'){
            destination[i]= origin[i] +'A'-'a';
         }
         else destination[i]=origin[i];
                i++;
      }
    destination[i]='\0';

return destination;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you might have a little mess there ^^

While the general idea is right, your method call doesn't work that way.

Try something like this

```
int main()
{
    char orig[30];
    char dest[30];

    printf("Write a string :");
    scanf("%s",orig);

    dest = uppercase(orig);
    printf("uppercase string = ",dest);


}



char[] uppercase(char origin){
    char destination[30];
    int i = 0;

      while(origin[i]!='\0'){

         if(origin[i]>='a'&& origin[i]<='z'){
            destination[i]= origin[i] +'A'-'a';
         }
         else destination[i]=origin[i];
                i++;
      }
    destination[i]='\0';

return destination;

}
```

though there might be even more Problems, but I am not sure which language you are programming in, so I can't really help you with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Im programming in C.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here:

1. You don't declare your **uppercase** function before you use it. While old C standards allow implicit function declarations, this doesn't work the way you want it to here. For more info see: [Implicit function declarations in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9182763/2327880)
2. You have type mismatches in your function signature. You should pass a char array either as **char *** or as **char []**, not as plain **char**. Same for the return type.
3. Not really an error, but it's good practice to use **fgets** instead of **scanf** to input strings, as this way you can protect against buffer overflow problems. See this too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1248017/2327880

This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// uppercase function declaration
char * uppercase(char *, char *);

int main() {

    char orig[31];
    char dest[31];

    printf("Write a string : ");

    // use fgets instead of scanf in order
    // to prevent buffer overflow problems
    fgets(orig, 31, stdin);

    // remove trailing newline
    orig[strlen(orig) - 1] = '\0';

    uppercase(dest, orig);
    printf("uppercase string = %s", dest);

    return 0;
}

// uppercase function definition
char * uppercase(char * destination, char * origin) {

    int i = 0;

    while(origin[i] != '\0') {

        if(origin[i] >= 'a' && origin[i] <= 'z') {
            destination[i] = origin[i] + 'A' - 'a';
        } else {
            destination[i] = origin[i];
        }

        i ++;
    }

    destination[i] = '\0';

    return destination;
}
```

Comment: I will use fgets.Thank you!