# Using strtok without including string.h, please explain behaviour

Tags: c, unix

So for the last several hours I have been trying to figure out why I was getting a seg fault while printing a freshly tokenized string using strtok(). FINALLY I realized I was not including string.h. After adding this line, I get the expected behaviour and no more seg fault... yay! However, I am new to c (although not programming) if someone could please explain the behaviour I was experiencing and answer the following...

1. Why was I not receiving an error when calling strtok() when it was not included?
2. I read recently that if you do not include the string.h, the default method signature will be used. However, I want to use strtok()'s default sig so why am I still getting this undefined behaviour?

   ```
   char    str[]= "ls -l";    
   char *  p    = strtok (str, " ");

   printf ("%s\n",p);
   ```

Seg fault on the last line

Comment: Could you please add the code that compiles and segfaults because of missing <string.h>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is [implicit function declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9182835/1983495), you should use warnings to prevent that.

The segmentation fault was because the compiler thought that `strtok()` was returning an integer, so you was assigning a signed integer to a pointer, and then trying to dereference the pointer, which is Undefined Behavior and can result in a segmentation fault.

Also never try to access the returned pointer from `strtok()` without checking if it's `NULL` first

```
char  str[] = "ls -l";    
char *p     = strtok (str, " ");

if (p != NULL)
    printf ("%s\n", p);
```

because it returns `NULL` when no token is found.

Comment: I see now, c is an interesting language, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Once you get used to thinking like a c programmers, you will find other programming languages so dumb, and I don't like any programming language as much as I love c...

Comment: I have been mostly java, and a little app dev with C#. I wish I had began with c. I will accept your answer in 43 seconds when I'm able to :)

Comment: Your edit I know about :) just gave a quick code sample