# Datatype mismatch with arduino and coder.ceval

Tags: c++, matlab, arduino, simulink, matlab-coder

I'm writing a simulink device driver block for Arduino Due with the Matlab Function Approach as explained in the Simulink Device Driver guide. When I want to pass a double from the C++ code to the matlab function code with coder.ceval() I get a wrong number. Here is an example:

C++ function:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
extern "C" double dout_output()
{
return 50.5;
}
```

Matlab function in Simulink:

```
function x = example()
x = 0.0;
if strcmp(coder.target,'rtw'),
x = coder.ceval('dout_output');
end
```

When I run this code in external mode on an adruino due I don't get the 50.5 but a large number like 1113794816. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the header file containing the declaration of `dout_output` being included in the C code generated from the MATLAB Function code? If not, you'll likely see compiler warnings that say something about implicit `int` return type.

When C compilers don't have a declaration for a function, they may assume that the return type is `int`. Typically `sizeof(int) != sizeof(double)`. So this mismatch can cause surprising results. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182763/implicit-function-declarations-in-c) discusses that more.

Try to add:

```
coder.cinclude('dout_output.h');
```

to your MATLAB code where `dout_output.h` is replaced with the name of the header containing the declaration of `dout_output`.

You may also need to add an include directory to the custom code settings in:

```
"Configuration Parameters->Simulation Target->Custom Code->Include Directories"
```

and possibly:

```
"Configuration Parameters->Code Generation->Custom Code->Include Directories"
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`coder.ExternalDependency`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/encapsulate-interface-to-external-code.html) approach to encapsulate external code dependencies for your MATLAB code.

Comment: Thank you so much it works finally.
     coder.cinclude('nameHeader.h');   did the trick.