# Why crc32 value require -lz

Tags: c, linker, header-files, undefined-reference, crc32

I am generating a crc32 value by using `crc32(initial_crc_value,data,data_length);` . if I am not using `-lz` in linker options, I am getting linker error as

> "undefined reference to crc32".

I did not include any `zlib.h`. So, in which header file `crc32()` is declared? Why linker option `-lz` is sufficient to compile?

Comment: In which file crc32() is declared?

Comment: @user4790894 declaration and implementation are not the same thing. You can't compile if you just *declare* `crc32`. You have to have an *implementation* of it, which is in libz.so

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, the `crc32()` function is declared (prototyped) in `zlib.h` and defined in the [`zlib`](http://zlib.net/) library. So, to use the `crc32()`, you need to include the header and link with the library.

Now, coming to your questions,

> **1.** *if I am not using `-lz` in linker options, I am getting linker error*

Yes, because at the linking time compiler will not able to find the `crc32()` function definition without linking to the `zlib` library, which contains the function definition.

> **2.** *why linker option `-lz` is sufficient to compile?*

To be truthful, it is not sufficient and it *should be* producing error. However, your code *works* (compiles) without the header file, is because of the implicit declaration of a function is (*sadly, still*) supported by the compiler. If you enable proper warnings, you'll be at least warned by your compiler regarding this issue.

---

Regarding the *"implicit declaration"* of a function, the scenario is, if the compiler comes across a function call for which it did not *see* a prototype yet (In other words, have no information regarding the function definition), it assumes the function is defined with a return type of `int` and accepts any number of arguments. You can read more on this on the [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9182835/2173917)

Comment: How to enable proper warnings in gcc?

Comment: If the compiler considers the function as implicit declaration, then what is the implementation of the function? is it link with libz.so  or not?

Comment: @user4790894 see [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) article. However. most of the time, adding `-Wall` to your compilation statement will do the job for warning you for _almost_ all the _possible_ pitfalls.

Comment: @user4790894 even with an implicit declaration, if you're linking with the library, at compilation time it will find the same function. However, if the function signature differs (i.e., returns anything other that `int`), and the return value is used. it will invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).