# A beginner's hello world C program?

Tags: c

As I beginner, I typed the following hello world program on Code::Blocks -

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
    {
        printf("Hello world \n");
    }
```

Now, I click on 'Build and Run', and the output screen shows 'Hello world'.

However, the book I am reading from, suggests me to remove certain elements of the program to see what errors occur in the program.

I made 2 changes. First, I removed \n from the program. (The book tells me that without \n, there will be an error running the program) However, when I click on 'Build and Run', the output screen gives me the same output it did when it was without any errors.

The second change I made was removing #include from the program. Even now, the output screen shows the same output it did when it was free from errors.

Why is this happening? Please tell me how to fix this?

The compiler I am using is GNU GCC compiler.

**EDIT:** As suggested, I added -wall, -wextra, -pedantic. Now, when I click on 'Build and Run', it says cannot find -1-wall, -1-wextra and -1-pedantic and the program doesn't run. How to fix this now?

Comment: 1st. throw the book. There's no chance removing the '\n' will generate an error. 2nd. It's been a while, but somewhere in the back of my mind lies an idea that `printf` can work without includes

Comment: please tell me the name of the book.

Comment: "it was free from errors" - but was it free from *warnings* ? Add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your compiler flags. In the latter case you showed, without a prior decl, C will (non)helpfully assume a function returns `int` and takes variable parameters. i.e. `int printf();`. And given a big enough warning-hammer, will tell you it did so.

Comment: @Amit: Not in standard C. In standard C language `printf` never "worked" without being pre-declared with a prototype. `printf` is a variadic function. Even in the very first C standard (which allowed calling undeclared functions), an attempt to call a variadic function without declaring it first triggered undefined behavior. Which means that you have to either include `<stdio.h>` or at least manually provide a prototype for `printf`.

Comment: @user52976: Formally, your program already contains an error. In modern C plain `main()` is illegal. The explicit return type is required. It should be `int main()`.

Comment: No, no, no. It's not `-wall, -wextra, -pedantic`, it is `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. The `-Wxyz` means compile `With xyz`. Above that means `With all` `With extra` and `pendantic` warnings enabled. (don't ask me why there is no `-W` before `pedantic`...)

Comment: I added a downvote for the cross-posting.

Comment: For all the pedantics .... `-pedantic` doesn't really make sense without a `-std` option. I usually use `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra filename.c`. Not using a `-std` option is the same as using `-std=gnu89` and `pedantic` and `gnu89` make no sense together :-)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "(don't ask me why there is no `-W` before `pedantic`...)" but there can be! `-Wpedantic` works too. anyway, glad someone pointed out the case typos. one does not simply put any capitalisation into *n?x command-line tools.

Answer (score 5):

**Case 1:** your book is wrong. Removing `\n` will never raise any error. `\n` means [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) which will print a new line after *Hello World*.

**Case 2:** May be you are not building the code again, because without including the `stdio` (means standard input/output) you may not invoke `printf()` function if you use newer C standards (C99, C11). Read more about [stdio.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output).

Note that, in pre C99 standard if you remove the prototype (`#include <stdio.h>`) C will automatically provide an implicit declaration for a function. Which will look like this:

```
int printf();
```

means, it will take any number of arguments and return `int`. But in C99 implicit deceleration were removed. So most probably your compiler does not confront C99.

Take a look [here](http://ideone.com/SDhIdh), compile fine!

Read more about [implicit declarations in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182763/implicit-function-declarations-in-c).

**EDIT:** As AnT mentioned in the comment, removing `#include<stdio.h>`, the call to printf will "compile" in pre-C99 version of language. However, the call will produce undefined behavior. Variadic functions (like printf) have to be declared with prototype before the call even in C89/90. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: If you remove the prototype, the call to `printf` will formally "compile" in pre-C99 version of language. However, the call will produce undefined behavior. *Variadic* functions (like `printf`) have to be declared *with prototype* before the call even in C89/90. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: By default, GCC doesn't use C99, but it can be enabled with the compiler flag `-std=c99`

Answer (score 2):

1. Your program already contains an error. Functions in modern C have to be declared with an explicitly specified return type. Your `main()` is declared without a return type, which has been illegal since C99.
2. There are different kinds of "errors". Some errors cause compiler to issue a diagnostic message. Some errors simply make your program behave unpredictably at run time (exhibit undefined behavior). The latter might be harder to detect, since "unpredictable" might look perfectly fine on the first sight.

   In your case removing `#include <stdio.h>` will trigger a diagnostic message in C99-compiliant compiler, but will lead to mere undefined behavior in C89/90 compiler. Undefined behavior might still produce the same screen output as before.

Comment: Though it might be illegal for modern standards to declare main() without a return type, there's maximal a warning with gcc, even with `-std=c99 -pedantic `, when you declare main() without the int. In classic c, a function without a return type automatically assumed int as the return type. Actually its hard to write errors into the hello_world. Removing the `;` or one or both of the `{}` or `()` will be an error. Or mistyping main or printf.

Comment: @ikrabbe: GCC is known to be very permissive in that regard. It even allows skipping that `int` in C++ code... Anyway, GCC option for reporting constraint violations (i.e. errors) as actual compile errors is `-pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to write hello world

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        printf("hello world");
        return 0;
    }
```

This code consists of these commands:

`‍‍#include <stdio.h>‍`:
This command is a preprocessor that calls the stdio.h file and its functions such as printf can be used
Of course, you can see the exact functions in this file through this link https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/

`int main()`:
In fact, this command is read by the compiler and calls the main function, which is the default in the compiler

‍`printf("hello world")`:
The printf function means (print format) and is used to print text or numbers. They usually use the variable % to display to the user, for example `%d` and `%i` for variables that are integers and `%s`. Used for string variables

`return 0`:
This syntax is used to return to the function and only works in functions that are not output variables such as `void`, such as `int` and `float`, or `string`, `char`
so return 0 should be used for `int main()` function

```
cc [file]
```

is enough to compile it.
In `[file]`, you only write the name and extension of the file you want to compile, for example name file `hi.c` so `cc hi.c` and run this codes in linux with `./a.out` command.

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing any issue by removing \n because '\n' is a new line character.
So previously your output was 
**"Hello World

"** (newline)
And now your output is 
**"Hello World"**
That's why you don't see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for not getting an error while removing `\n` is because it is an [escape equence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) that denotes a newline character. Adding or removing escape sequence would not result in error until and unless other part of code is not affected. For example if you remove only `\` from `\n`, this would result in error since your `"` would be escaped as `\"`.

For the second case, either you are not building the code again before running it or your IDE would be setting it by itself. Removing the `#include` line would result in error since your `printf()` function is declared in the `stdio.h` header file. Without the function declaration, calling a fucntion would result in an error.

---

If you are using any shell, it would be better if you write your code in a text editor and compile it using gcc in shell as:

```
gcc filename.c
```

The executable would be named by default as `a.out`. More about `gcc` can be read using `man gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

Case 2:

Without the `printf()` prototype in `#include<stdio.h>`, many compliers use a pre-C99 standard.  That assumes the function has the prototype of `int printf(...)` where all arguments, including the format go through the *usual* argument promotions with no type checking.  Since code passed the expected format parameter and and `int` was returned, code worked.  Had code been `printf(5.0)`, it likely would compile but crash on execution.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the "\n" from the " Hello world \n" won't produce any errors, but it *MAY* produce a different result on execution. Depending on the operating system, it may write nothing until the next time a "\n" is sent to stdout, or until the output buffer flushes.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<Stdio.h> 
//this contains the function used to print which is printf(); also puts();
int main()//The the main function in code simply the one with highest importance
{//opening braces
printf("hello world\n");//this prints the word and \n enters a newline
puts("hello world");//does the exact same thing
return 0; //means if the program runs correctly then return the no zero to screen
}//closing braces
//anything that has those 2 forward slashes are comments and they aren't compiled
```

Comment: step by step explanation to c 's hello world