# How to remove this error "implicit declaration of function ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel is invalid in c99" in xcode 7?

Tags: ios, operating-system, xcode7, abaddressbook

I am using

```
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(PhoneValue,(__bridge CFTypeRef)mblNum.number,kABPhoneMobileLabel, NULL);
```

but its giving me error. How to overcome this? I am developing an app for OS x.

Comment: You're calling an undeclared function. You need to include the appropriate headers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implicit function declarations in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182763/implicit-function-declarations-in-c)