# Why does mingw-gcc allow getch() to be used unconditionally?

Tags: c, linux, windows, gcc

I recently started porting a TON of my C programs to a Windows environment, from my previous Linux development PC. I noticed something a bit off about `mingw`'s Windows GCC implementation.

In Windows, I found a lovely function called `getch`. It's easy, it's immediate... and it's also non-standard.

I'd like to focus of the "non-standard" part of it. Specifically, I want to know why `mingw-gcc` allows me to use it, without using anything but the standard libraries.

Assume we have a program that prints "Hello, World!", a NL and CR, and then waits for a key and a return:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char str[14] = "Hello, World!"; //13 characters and a terminator
    printf("%s\n\r", str);
    scanf("%c");
    return 0;
}
```

Now, let's change a bit of that program to use `getch`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char str[14] = "Hello, World!"; //Again, 13 characters and a terminator
    printf("%s\n\r", str);
    getch(); //See? now it uses getch.
    return 0;
}
```

The interesting part is, Isn't `getch` a call made by the `conio.h` library for old DOS/Win32 environments? The compiler doesn't even give a warning. Why does this work?

Here's something I find even a bit more unsettling:

```
int main(void) //literally NOTHING included
{
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

What on earth? I know for a fact that `getch` does not exist on Linux environments (natively, anyways). So, where is the compiler getting this call from?

My best guess (please correct me if I am wrong) is that the decision to link whatever has `getch` is made at *link* time, not compile time.

In any case, this seems a little odd to me. Why does an implementation of GCC automatically include *clearly* non-standard capability on Windows?

Comment: Did you know that you can call functions without declaring them in C?

Comment: @immibis I do. But what I'm asking is how and why GCC of all compilers interprets that `getch` call and knows what to do with it without any guidance whatsoever,.

Comment: `conio.h` is a header, not a library. It declares functions (and defines types, etc). You're not compiling with any warning options worth mentioning because if you were, the compiler would complain that you've not declared `getch()` before you used it (and it would complain about the missing argument in the `scanf("%c")` call in the first program). The MinGW compiler links with the local C library — it is a Minimal GNU environment for Windows, so it links with the MS C runtime library (libraries) which include `getch()`.  If you compile in C99 or C11 mode, you have to declare functions first.

Comment: Also, the line ending sequence on Windows is `\r\n` and not `\n\r`.  Further complicating things is that text mode input operations will translate the native `\r\n` to just `\n` and the output operations will translate `\n` to `\r\n`.  This transform does not occur with binary mode I/O.

Comment: @MasonWatmough Same way it knows how to call `printf` when you call `printf`.

Comment: @immibis That's not what I mean. `printf` is included and linked because it's part of the standard library. `getch` is not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That makes more sense. I was not aware that `mingw-gcc` was treating Windows C and its parts as standard, because according to Windows, I suppose it would be.

Comment: @MasonWatmough `getch` is part of the standard library on Windows.

Comment: in the 'original' code, the `scanf("%c");` raises a warning because no parameter containing address of a char for the format specifier '%c' to input to.  This needs correction

Comment: in the 'windows' version of the posted code, the compiler will raise the warning: "warning: implicit declaration of function 'getch' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]".    Save your self lots of aggravation and use `getchar()`.

Comment: Try invoking the compiler in standard mode.  It defaults to "useful mode" . E.g. use switches `-std=c11 -pedantic`. You should get messages from the compiler for your last example, even in the default mode.

Comment: Not *directly* relevant, but you should note that MinGW is using the C runtime shipped with Windows, which is designed only for two uses: use by Windows itself, and use by programs compiled in Visual Studio 6, circa 1998.  So as standard libraries go, it isn't very. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compilation step works (though it should produce a warning) because, traditionally, C allows you to call functions that haven't been declared, [provided that they return an int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9182835/886887) which getch() does.

The linking step works because the C runtime library that MinGW uses is a single library, i.e., it provides all the Visual C runtime library functions, including the non-standard ones.  MinGW presumably links with it by default because (apart from very rare edge cases) it is always needed, even if all you want is a main() function that does nothing. :-)

---

It should also be mentioned that the library in question does not officially support third-party use, except by applications built in Visual Studio 6.  The more modern runtimes have deprecated `getch` in favour of the equivalent but standards compliant `_getch`, but VS6 predates that change.

Answer (score -1):

The compile step will probably 'work' because compilers (at least older versions of compilers — we know that Visual Studio is not up to date with the latest C standards) will assume the return type and the parameters are all `int`.

The link step will need the appropriate library linked in.

Comment: In the absence of a prototype, the compiler does _not_ assume that the parameters are all `int`; it applies the default promotions (shorter than `int` to `int`; `float` to `double`) and makes no assumptions about the number of arguments or the types (except that it knows the function is not a variadic function with `...` at the end of its argument list — such functions must always be properly declared, even in C89/C90).

Comment: 'modern' compilers don't make the assumption, however, Visual Studio is way behind and still makes the assumption.  Also, the discussion is not about a variadic function.

Comment: Ancient compilers don't make the assumption that the parameters are all `int` either.  To think otherwise is a nonsense — you'd never be able to pass a `double` or a pointer to any function if what you said were true.  Granted, the discussion is not about variadic functions; they are marginally relevant since the requirements on using them is different from the requirements on using non-variadic (fixed argument) functions.

Comment: Note that the OP isn't using VS anyway.