# Function visible even if not included in C

Tags: c, eclipse, static-libraries

I have defined function `A` in `main.c` file. I have created three libraries which use the function `A` without importing anything. The code works but I have only one warning: `implicit declaration of function 'A' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`.

How is it possible that the function `A` works in a function `B` defined in a separate file without importing it?
How is it possible that I have only one warning when function `A` is called by other functions except function `B`?

Comment: It does not make sense to define functions in main.c and call them from other files. That program design is complete spaghetti.

Comment: BTW: the warning: _implicit declaration of function ..._ should be considered as an error nowadays.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Indeed. C standard explicitly forbids the same.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182763/implicit-function-declarations-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `C`, we don't "import" functions. We compile individual translation units to object files and then link all of them together to form the binary / executable.

In the linking phase, linker checks the object files for required symbols and references and links them together to produce the single executable (thus making the function call possible at runtime).

In your case, the compiler does not "see" the function declaration at the time of the call (*so, it does not have any idea of the function signature, which can be a potential pitfall, that is why you have the "warning"*), but in the linking phase, linker is able to find the reference to the function (assuming both the translation units are being linked together to form the binary) and creates the binary.

FWIW, implicit function declarations are non-standard as per the latest C standards. You **must** forward declare the function (provide a prototype) before you can actually use the function. Quoting `C11`, Foreword,

> Major changes in the second edition included:
>
> [....]
>
> — remove implicit function declaration

Answer (score 5):

Global non-static symbols (variables *and* functions) have by default *external [linkage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration#Linkage)* meaning they can be accessed from other [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

Comment: This would also explain why you can use printf without including stdio.h.

Comment: @Coldspeed Ehr, not really. That has more to do with the implicit declarations done by the compiler (which was marked as obsolete in C99 and removed in C11 I think). Because the C compiler infers the declaration from the first use of the function, if you try to call `printf` with other arguments later the compiler will think it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling:

- During compilation each file is compiled separately and at last a .o
  file is generated from a .c file.
- For each function called in the file compiler expect's the function definition or at least the function's declaration.
- In case of missing the definition or declaration you get a warning from the compiler like implicit declaration of function 'A'
  [-Wimplicit-function-declaration].
- In your case as the function definition is in another file you must at least include the function declaration in your include file.

Linking:

- Linking refers to the creation of a single executable file from
  multiple  object files. In this step, it is common that the linker
  will complain about undefined functions.
- As the function A in main.c is globally defined it will be used by the library.