# Is there such thing as implicit declaration in c++?

Tags: c++, implicit-declaration

I was burnt just now. I hadn't enabled warnings while compiling my c code. I was using `atof` without including `stdlib.h`. So the `atof` was using implicit declaration which had default return type of `int`. So the code wasn't working.
I was wondering if the concept of implicit declarations also applies to c++?

Comment: Function prototypes are required in C++. Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem you observed?

Comment: @GregHewgill: He's talking about [this C (mis)feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182763/implicit-function-declarations-in-c).

Comment: @NicolBolas: I understand, but the question is about C++, not C.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Yes, he's asking if C++ has this C feature. He doesn't need to provide an SSCCE to ask for that. Basically, everything but the last sentence is background information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ does not allow [implicit function declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182763/implicit-function-declarations-in-c). Indeed, even C99/11 doesn't allow them. GCC compiles C by default as C89, which is why you got the error you did.