# Why is my factorial program working but my almost identical pow program is not working?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization, pow

Here is my factorial program—this is executing and giving a correct result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;

    printf("enter the no=");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    fun(n);
    printf("%d\n", fun(n));

    return 0;
}

int fun(int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return fun(n - 1) * n;
}
```

This is my program to compute the power of a number—this is giving 0 instead of the correct result and yet is almost identical:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int m, n;

    printf("enter the no=");
    scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
    pow(m, n);
    printf("%d\n", pow(m, n));

    return 0;
}
int pow(int m, int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return pow(m, n - 1) * m;
}
```

Both are running on same compiler.

Why is my factorial program working but my almost identical power program is not working?

Comment: As the two answers I see note, you have an unnecessary call to `pow()` in that code.  I don't think the answers mention that you have an unnecessary call to `fun()` in your first program.   Note that if you enter a number that is 13 or larger, your factorial code will suffer from a signed integer overflow, leading to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Mine does.

Comment: I see mention of the unnecessary call to `pow()` and recognized that both answers mention that.  I still don’t see the reference to `fun()` by name, but on a re-re-read, I do see a contextual reference to it, which is why I missed it before.

Answer (score 5):

A few issues are present here. First and foremost, you didn't declare a prototype for your function before calling it the first time. To do so, you need to place `int pow(int, int);` above `main`. This lets the compiler know exactly what your function expects and what it returns.

Ordinarily, this wouldn't cause the behavior you're seeing (though it *is* bad practice), but there's also already a function named `pow` in the C library. Since you never gave it a definition of your own, it's being implicitly included in your code. Now, it's expecting you to put two doubles in and get a double out.

Add the prototype at the top and rename your function, and you'll fix both of these issues at once.

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/CanineDisgustingVirtualmemory)

(Also, for what it's worth, you've got an unnecessary call.)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int powr(int, int);    // helps avoid compiler warnings

int main()
{
    int m, n;

    printf("enter the no=");
    scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
    powr(m, n);             // unnecessary
    printf("%d\n", powr(m, n));

    return 0;
}

int powr(int m, int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return powr(m, n - 1) * m;
}
```

Comment: You might note that there's no need for the first call to `powr`, and that having a function prototype is required for everything but C99.

Comment: It might be the problem. The C standard allows for implicit inclusion.

Comment: @Bathsheba: C++ allows standard headers to include other standard headers. The C standard does not.

That said, gcc does have a built-in named `pow()` and what happens on my simple tests is that the code gets compiled using the built-in's prototype (`double pow(double, double)`) but the function defined in the source file is what gets called (incorrectly). The general advice of declaring functions and objects before calling them is always good.

Answer (score 3):

For a little backstory behind this: The GNU C compiler (presumably what you're using) has implicit declarations for most of the Standard C Library functions that can be optimized in target-specific ways. `pow` is one of them.

To fix this, you should rename your `pow` function to something not reserved by the Standard C library and provide a prototype for it, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int power(int m, int n);
```

If you compile in strict C89/C90 compliance mode, you don't even need to provide a prototype due to [implicit function declaration rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182763/implicit-function-declarations-in-c). However, if you compile with *any other standard* (which is the default and highly recommended), you'll need to provide a prototype for that function, as shown above.

I'd also like to note that you have an unnecessary call to your power-computing program (also present in the factorial-computing program):

```
scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
power(m, n); // here
printf("%d\n", power(m, n));
```