# Why wprintf() function doesn't give me output with TEXT macro?

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to compile WinApi app as followed but i get no output -

```
#include <windows.h>
#define UNICODE 

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{

  wprintf(TEXT("%s"), TEXT("Hello")) ;

}
```

Also i have this output from GCC -

```
app.c: In function 'WinMain':
app.c:9:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'wprintf'; did you mean 'wsprintf'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    9 |   wprintf(TEXT("%s"), TEXT("Hello")) ;
      |   ^~~~~~~
      |   wsprintf
```

However, if i rewrite function in the following way i have correct output, but same warning from compiler appears -

```
#include <windows.h>
#define UNICODE 

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
  
  wprintf(L"%s", L"Hello") ; 

}
```

I am using `GCC 13.2.0 from MSYS32` and compiling this app with no flags as follows : `gcc app.c -o app`

- Why first variant has no output, but second does? Doesn't statement `wprintf(TEXT("%s"), TEXT("Hello")) ;` expand to `wprintf(L"%s", L"Hello") ;`  ?
- What does this compiler warning mean ?

Comment: You need to include the correct header files for [`wprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwprintf).

Comment: Also, if you're specifically use a wide-character function, use the `L` prefix explicitly, there's just no need to use any macros like `TEXT`. Especially since you define the dependency macro `UNICODE` wrong, so `TEXT` will give you a *narrow* character string.

Comment: 1. - I've included `wchar.h`. Now `TEXT` macro variant still outputs nothing, but also i have another warning.
- And second variant just outputs `H`

2. What do you mean by "define the dependency macro `UNICODE` wrong" ? My linter says that `TEXT()` macro expands to `L""`

Comment: Order matters... The `TEXT` macro is defined by a header file that is included (directly or indirectly) by `windows.h`. If the `UNICODE` macro isn't defined when you include `windows.h`, then `TEXT` will be defined for narrow characters and strings.

Comment: `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` need to be defined before any includes in order to have the desired effect. You should generally add them to the compile command line so they are used for every file.

Comment: ```#include <wchar.h>``` is necessary.

Comment: There is literally no reason to use [generic-text mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/generic-text-mappings) in 2024. They provide zero practical benefit and are way too hard to use correctly. (You'd have to use `_tprintf()` and use the `_T` macro rather than `TEXT`. Every other combination is incorrect.)

Comment: And you'd need to define the `_UNICODE` preprocessor symbol, not `UNICODE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's cover the second question first:

> What does this compiler warning mean ?

The warning notes that you're using a feature of the C Programming Language so dangerous that it was promoted to an error with C99: Whenever the compiler sees a function call expression with a function name it doesn't know, it will go ahead and [invent a declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9182763). The following [example](https://godbolt.org/z/r1rsTn6Yn) compiles even though it shouldn't.

Tragically, the linker somehow discovers the `wprintf()` symbol and produces a binary it should never have. Worse, GCC doesn't implement C99 by default, so passing `-std=c99` won't save you.

The solution is simple: To call [`wprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwprintf) you must `#include <wchar.h>`. This introduces the declaration for `wprintf()` so that the compiler can produce the correct function call code.

---

The first question requires a bit more text to explain. The main takeaway is:

**Don't use [generic-text mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/generic-text-mappings).**

They were introduced to aid developers in transitioning from Win9x to WinNT-based systems by providing a crude translation layer to account for different default character encodings (ANSI codepage encodings for Win9x and UCS-2/UTF-16 for WinNT).

> Why first variant has no output, but second does?

They aren't equivalent. The first piece of code constructs **narrow** character string literals. Using the `TEXT()` macro doesn't do anything. The specific issue is here:

```c
#include <windows.h>
#define UNICODE
```

This instructs the compiler to process all preprocessor directives from the *<windows.h>* header and its transitive dependencies, and *then* defines the `UNICODE` preprocessor symbol. Doing this doesn't retroactively change what `TEXT()` means: It's still just a no-op.

That leads the way to the third question you didn't ask:

> Why does this even compile?

This is another feature of the C Programming Language: A pointer is just a pointer. The fact that you can associate a type to the pointee leaves the compiler [unimpressed](https://godbolt.org/z/9P3cobPbM) (modulo a warning). It asked for a pointer and a pointer it got, so that's that.

Changing the order would make the two programs identical. But that would still be wrong, even if inconsequential.

---

Again, **you should not be using generic-text mappings**, but if you must, at least don't get it wrong. With "getting it wrong" being the default, let's quickly cover the rules:

- Generic-text mappings are controlled through the preprocessor symbols `UNICODE`, `_UNICODE`, `MBCS`, and `_MBCS`. Always pass them on the compiler command line, e.g., `-D _UNICODE`.
- The preprocessor symbols control two independent areas: The Win32 API surface (`UNICODE`/`MBCS`) and the C Runtime (`_UNICODE`/`_MBCS`). [TEXT vs. _TEXT vs. _T, and UNICODE vs. _UNICODE](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040212-00/?p=40643) explains this in more detail.
- String literals must be enclosed in `TEXT()` or `_TEXT()`/`_T()` macros. Choose the correct macro depending on the area the function belongs to, e.g., `_TEXT()` for the CRT.
- Always call the generic-text mapping of functions. The CRT has (non-standard) extensions that have a `_t`-prefix, e.g., `_tprintf()`. For the Win32 API, the generic-text mappings don't have the `A` or `W` suffix.

This would be the proper implementation using generic-text mappings:

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
  _tprintf(_TEXT("%s"), _TEXT("Hello")) ;
}
```

You can forget everything you read here if you don't use generic-text mappings. You aren't losing anything in doing so.

Comment: Are there any better options for building `Win32Api C application` than `GCC` ? (Except `Visual Studio`)

Comment: Yes, pretty much *anything* is better than GCC. Visual Studio (and Visual Studio Build Tools) are supported build environments, and Clang is semi-supported.