# Make a specific gcc warning into an error

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, warnings, compiler-flags

So I know I can turn warnings into errors using -Werror=... but I want to make the following warning into an error:

"Class xxx has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor"

The only way I know you can get this error is by turning on the overly obnoxious -Weffc++ flag.  Is there a way (or what is the sub-flag in -Weffc++ for this warning) to just print this warning and then turn it into an error?

Thanks!

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475407/make-one-gcc-warning-an-error

Comment: I've seen that post, but wouldn't that mean I would still need to have the -Weffc++ flag on and then in Werror=... I catch the specific warning?  I just want to print out the specific warning too.

Comment: What is the exact question, how to enable that warning? how to make that warning (and that alone) an error (while allowing for other warnings)?

Comment: How do I enable that warning without enabling all the other warnings that come along with -Weffc++ and then I want to take that isolated warning and make it into an error.

Comment: Ok, the flag is -Wnon-virtual-dtor now I need to turn it into an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-Wnon-virtual-dtor` is the name of the specific warning that is turned on by `-Weffc++`. To turn any warning into an error, you use `-Werror=...`. So if the warning were `-Wspam`, making it into an error would be `-Werror=spam`. So in this case, you would use `-Werror=non-virtual-dtor`.

However, I don't feel that this warning is especially useful if you are on GCC 4.8 and up. Then you have access to the superior `-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor`:

> Warn when `delete` is used to destroy an instance of a class that
>   has virtual functions and non-virtual destructor. It is unsafe to
>   delete an instance of a derived class through a pointer to a base
>   class if the base class does not have a virtual destructor.  This
>   warning is enabled by `-Wall`.

Note that `g++ -Wspam -Werror=spam` is the same thing as `g++ -Werror=spam`. Turning a warning into an error automatically turns that warning on.

On a related note, you're not the only one who thinks that [`-Weffc++` is a little overzealous](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16166).

Comment: Great answer, thank you!  I was aware of the -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor; however, we are confined to using an older version of GCC.